# I don't see an explanatory legend in SAS proc freq

Tags: sas

I have a problem with the legend not being visible at cross tabulation in porc freq in SAS. How can I show it?

I see only a table:
[image]

But I want to also see a legend:
[image]

Comment: Show the code that generated the graphic without the legend. AFAIK it's part of the default though one looks like PDF versus HTML output.

Comment: proc freq data=&dane;
 tables &zm_i*&zm_j /chisq;
run;

Comment: This is the proc freq code and its in a html output

Comment: There has to be more code around it, otherwise the default output is as shown in your second post. The second post is the default settings. Some settings have been changed to get the first table. So show the full code you've used.

Comment: ods layout end;
ods html close;
  %let i = %eval(&i + 2); 
 %end;
%mend;

Comment: This is full code

Comment: Please post the code as an edit to your question not in the comments, very hard to read. You also need to show how the macro is called because we have no idea what those macro parameters are. But I think your layout is causing the issue. If you try a PROC FREQ in a clean session you'll see the standard output. So something in your code there is truncating the titles. Try removing them one at a time until you find what is causing the issue.

Comment: Add `options mprint symbolgen;` before the macro call, run the code and post the full log. That may have the options.

Comment: I post the code. The problem occurs even when I run the proc freq alone outside the macro.

Comment: Then your PROC FREQ template has been destroyed somehow, you'll need to find someone else's proc freq template and replace yours or reinstall SAS.

Answer (score 0):

`PROC FREQ` does not have a legend per se, but you can use the `title` statement to put some information there, or `footer`.

If you want better control, use `PROC TABULATE` which has substantial ability to customize the output, including the `box` option which places whatever information you want in the top-left corner of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following:

```
proc template;
source Base.Freq.CrossTabFreqs;
run;
```

Then check your log, you should see:

```
define crosstabs Base.Freq.CrossTabFreqs;
    notes "Crosstabulation table";
    cellvalue Frequency Expected Deviation CellChiSquare TotalPercent Percent RowPercent ColPercent CumColPercent;
    header TableOf ControllingFor;
    footer NoObs Missing;
```

If you do not, that means that someone has modified your PROC FREQ base template and that's why it's not showing. In this case you would need to replace your default SAS installation templates by obtaining clean copies from a different source. It may also need to align with your SAS version.

If you have a colleague or different SAS installation that is operating as expected, you can run the PROC TEMPLATE above, then copy the code from the log and re-create the template as:

```
proc template;
<insert copied code from log>;
run;
```

And you probably realize, but this is why modifying templates is generally a last resort for customizing data/output and usually you should never modify the default templates.